# verify if the value of some keys are in the payload

Tags: dataweave

I have this input:

```json
[
  {
    "building": 222,
    "default": {
      "money": 0.22,
      "perHour": null
    },
    "appPricing": [
      {
        "pricing": {
          "money": 1.25,
          "perHour": null
        },
        "schedules": [
          {
            "daysOfWeek": [
              "FRIDAY",
              "MONDAY"
            ],
            "end": "21:59:00",
            "start": "08:00:00"
          },
          {
            "days": [
              "TUESDAY",
              "WEDNESDAY",
              "THURSDAY"
            ],
            "end": "15:59:00",
            "start": "11:00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to filter after a specific day, a specific end time, and a start time.
Here is the output:

```json
{ 
  "money": 0.22, 
  "perMinute": null, 
  "perSession": null
}
```

Thanks And I want to filter after a specific day, a specific end time, and a start time.

Comment: Please provide example filter values and expected output for those inputs.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter in a filter?"

Comment: @HarshankBansal I think here there should be a filter after the payload and after that a filter after the schedules array.

Comment: What is the criteria to compare those inputs?

Comment: Also where the values of perMinute and perSession in the output are coming from?

Comment: @aled the values will come as queryParams from the request.

Comment: So they are additional inputs not calculated in the output? Clarification of the filtering criteria is still needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to filter pricing based on schedules and return default pricing in case no pricing found. The key is the internal filter to return the boolean condition, I have used `isEmpty` with `!` operator for the same.

However, I see there is a difference in the output vs the input. For example, perMinute and perSession fields in output. So please use the below script as starting point, and extend/modify the script according to your requirements.

Hope this helps!

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var inp = {
    day: "THURSDAY",
    endTime: "16:59:00",
    startTime: "11:00:00"
}

fun matchSchedules (schedules) = 
    !isEmpty (schedules filter (($.daysOfWeek contains inp.day)
                    and $.endTime == inp.endTime
                    and $.startTime == inp.startTime))
---
((payload[0].appPricing filter ((price) -> matchSchedules(price.schedules)))[0].pricing) default payload[0]."default"
```